# Return a substring from a field in SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm hoping one of you knowledgable lot can help me out with this...

I have a field in my DB which contains HTML.  Within this HTML, in each record there is a link with parameters included.

eg.

```
<a href='http://mysite.com/clickme.aspx?ctid=31' title='Click Here !' target='_blank'>Click this link</a>
```

All I want to return is the ID of the record, and the value of the parameter CTid (CTid could be anything between 2 digits and 12 digits long)

So, what I want returned is:

```
ID ¦ CTid ¦
73 ¦ 31   ¦
```

I've tried using PATINDEX but it's not doing the trick for me (because I have to specify the length of the string returned)

```
SELECT id, SUBSTRING(content, PATINDEX('%CTid%', content), 12) AS CTid
FROM ARTICLES
WHERE content LIKE '%CTid%'
```

returns:

```
   ID ¦ CTid         ¦
   73 ¦ ctid=31' tit ¦
```

Can anyone shed some light on a good way of doing this ?

I'll be returning several thousand rows so would rather stay away from cursors and intensive operations if possible.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What DBMS are you using? In the example you provide, are you trying to return 31?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, SUBSTRING(content, PATINDEX('%CTid%', content) + 5, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(content, PATINDEX('%CTid%', content) + 5, 12)) - 1) AS CTid       
FROM ARTICLES
WHERE content LIKE '%CTid%'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this query, works in ms sql server:

```
SELECT ID, SUBSTRING(CTid, 0, PATINDEX('%''%', CTid))
FROM(
    SELECT ID, SUBSTRING(content, PATINDEX('%CTid%', content)+5, 12)+'''' AS CTid
    FROM ARTICLES
    WHERE content LIKE '%CTid%'
)X
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply, I appreciate it, but I'm going to mark Alexander's answer as correct as it was the most straightforward.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(yourSQLString, "=", "."), 2),"'", "."),1)

This requires that **yourSQLString** starts at least 1 digit before the **=** and finishes at least 1 digit after **'**

Comment: Thank you very much for reply, I appreciate it, but I'm going to mark Alexander's answer as correct as it was the most straightforward.
Thanks again.